# Javascript Function fails with IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

The function below, bound to button's onclick handler, is running with all browsers but not with Internet Explorer 9. Blank window with the message on the taskbar:"Downloading data `http://0.0.0.0/..`".
Here is the screenshot:

[image]

```
 function publishAd(i){
    $('.publishad .form .put input').hide();
    $('.publishad .form .put img').show();
    var mysarr = {};
    PopAjaxPost('ilan/publishad/' + i, mysarr, function (data) {
        if (data.Durum == '1') {
            ibFunc.openBoxOpen("/ilan/popup/publish/" + i);
            $('.publishad .form .put input').show();
            $('.publishad .form .put img').hide();
        }
        else {
            $('.publishad .form .put input').show();
            $('.publishad .form .put img').hide();
        }
    });
}
```

PopAjaxPost Function:

```
function PopAjaxPost(a, c, e) { $("span.popupbilgilendirme").show(); 
$("img.loodingimg").show();
$("span.popupbilgilendirme").html(""); 
$.post(AjaxDomain() + a, c, e, "json").error(function () {$("span.popupbilgilendirme").show();    
$("span.popupbilgilendirme").css("color", "red");
$("span.popupbilgilendirme").html("Bir hata oldu...") }).complete(function () {  
$("img.loodingimg").hide(); $("span.formguncelleme").fadeOut(5E3) }) 
}
```

What's the possible cause?

Comment: what is PopAjaxPost ?

Comment: PopAjaxPost has been added

Comment: No console errors at all

Comment: Open F12 Developer Tools and use the Network tools, or use Fiddler, execute the code and watch the network traffic.  Do you get a 500 error code back at any point?  Do you see traffic leaving the page at all?

Comment: OK, I will. It's on customer's premises. What if there is 500 error? What will I be supposed to do?